# php string matching with wildcard *?

Tags: php, regex, string-matching

I want to give the possibility to match string with wildcard `*`.

Example

```
$mystring = 'dir/folder1/file';
$pattern = 'dir/*/file';

stringMatchWithWildcard($mystring,$pattern);  //> Returns true
```

Example 2:

```
$mystring = 'string bl#abla;y';
$pattern = 'string*y'; 

stringMatchWithWildcard($mystring,$pattern);  //> Returns true
```

I thought something like:

```
function stringMatch($source,$pattern) {
    $pattern = preg_quote($pattern,'/');        
    $pattern = str_replace( '\*' , '.*?', $pattern);   //> This is the important replace
    return (bool)preg_match( '/^' . $pattern . '$/i' , $source );
}
```

Basically replacing `*` to `.*?` (considering in `*nix` environment `*` matches `empty` string)  *©vbence*

Any improvments/suggests?

// Added `return (bool)` because preg_match returns int

Answer (score 61, accepted):

There is no need for `preg_match` here. PHP has a wildcard comparison function, specifically made for such cases:

> [`fnmatch()`](http://php.net/fnmatch)

And `fnmatch('dir/*/file', 'dir/folder1/file')` would likely already work for you. But beware that the `*` wildcard would likewise add further slashes, like preg_match would.

Comment: hi mario. fnmatches has some other feature like `[]`. I just need `*` as "special char"

Comment: fnmatch is not supported on non-POSIX systems. (I see that php5.3+ also supports windows now). So this is not always the best way

Answer (score 4):

You should just use `.*` instead.

```
$pattern = str_replace( '*' , '.*', $pattern);   //> This is the important replace
```

Edit: Also your `^` and `$` were in the wrong order.

```
<?php

function stringMatchWithWildcard($source,$pattern) {
    $pattern = preg_quote($pattern,'/');        
    $pattern = str_replace( '\*' , '.*', $pattern);   
    return preg_match( '/^' . $pattern . '$/i' , $source );
}

$mystring = 'dir/folder1/file';
$pattern = 'dir/*/file';

echo stringMatchWithWildcard($mystring,$pattern); 



$mystring = 'string bl#abla;y';
$pattern = 'string*y'; 

echo stringMatchWithWildcard($mystring,$pattern);
```

Working demo: http://www.ideone.com/mGqp2

Comment: I don't know if I want to give the possibility to match this `'dir//file'` with `'dir/*/file'`

Comment: `.*` is greedy, it  will eat all the rest of your string, no just the minimal number of characters to continue with the patters. So if you have anything after `.*` the result will be always false.

Comment: I thought that was exactly what you wanted to do with `.+?` from your description.

Comment: @vbence `preg_match('/.*a/', 'aa')` ?

Comment: Ok it seems `match` will give the same results.

Comment: @vbence maybe in this case it's the same with or without `?` because 1) there aren't any () capturing parts 2) it's defined with `^ $`

Answer (score 3):

```
.+?
```

Causes non-greedy matching for all characters. This is NOT equal to "*" becuase it will not match the empty string.

The following pattern will match the empty string too:

```
.*?
```

so...

```
stringMatchWithWildcard ("hello", "hel*lo"); // will give true
```

Comment: do you think I should allow for empty string? Consider dir too:  `'dir//file'` matching `'dir/*/file'` ?

Comment: If you want it to work analogous to how OS shells work, then you have to allow for the empty string. Just try `echo > hello` followed by `dir hello*` in windows or `ls hello*` in *nix. In this context * matches the empty string.

Comment: It would be polite to give a comment with your -1.

Comment: ah nice! thanks for the *nix comparsion! (also i didnt -1 your answer, no reason for me to do that)

Comment: @yes123 Yep, I know, not accusing. :)

Comment: I would like to hear the downvote reason here because acutally i am using this lol

Comment: @dynamic Obviously it worked.... and i really dislike uncommented downvotes... random people picking up points. So... Upvote

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing up ending (`$`) and beginning (`^`). This:

```
preg_match( '/$' . $pattern . '^/i' , $source );
```

Should be:

```
preg_match( '/^' . $pattern . '$/i' , $source );
```

Answer (score 0):

The one problem you'll have is that the call to `preg_quote()` will escape the asterisk character. Given that, your `str_replace()` will replace the `*`, but not the escape character in front of it.

Therefore you should change the `str_replace('*' ..)` with `str_replace('\*'..)`

Comment: i missed that from the documetnatnion my bad. fixed

Answer (score 0):

```php
$pattern = str_replace( '\*' , '.+?', $pattern);   // at least one character
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code - have a look at the other answers to this question for some inspiration