# Is it possible to compare two strings while ignoring one of the characters php?

Tags: php, string-comparison

If you have

```
$str1 = "h*llo";
$str2 = "hello";
```

is it possible to quickly compare them without first having to remove the * from str1, and  the matching indexed character from str2?

The solution would need to work regardless of how many * are in the string, eg:

```
$str1 = "h*l*o";
$str2 = "hello";
```

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: You are looking for [`fnmatch()`](http://php.net/fnmatch).

Comment: possible duplicate of [php string matching with wildcard \*?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163055/php-string-matching-with-wildcard)

Comment: @mario Didn't know about that function! Probably a more complete/faster/better overall method than using regular expressions.

Comment: Thank guys - fnmatch examples don't seem to be working. I'll check if it's available on my server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, with regex, and more specifically [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) for PHP. What you are looking for are "wildcards".

This is untested but should work for you:

```
$str1 = "h*llo";
$str2 = "hello";

//periods are a wildcards in regex
if(preg_match("/" . preg_quote(str_replace("*", ".*", $str1), "/") . "/", $str2)){
    echo "Match!";
} else {
    echo "No match";
}
```

EDIT: This should work for your case:

```
$str1 = "M<ter";
$str2 = "Moter";

//periods are a wildcards in regex
if(preg_match("/" . str_replace("\<", ".*", preg_quote($str1, "/")) . "/", $str2)){
    echo "Match!";
} else {
    echo "No match";
}
```

Comment: That's what I'd prefer still. +1 for thinking about preg_quote. Though replace `*` with `.*` to match multiple chars.

Comment: Thanks for the `.*` suggestion, I'm not that great at regex.

Comment: Perhaps I should have not used the wildcard symbol. My text has the character "<" in the place of any punctuation and accents, and now I need to compare the strings. eg "M<ter" to "Motor" (lame example).

Comment: @Shaun Just change `str_replace("*"` to `str_replace("<"`

Comment: Hi John.  The example you've given gives "no match". Should it be a match?

Comment: To be sure, I'll update the question with the code that is relevant to your `<` case.

Comment: Thank you John. That one displays "No match" too - is it supposed to display "Match!"?

Comment: WOWWWWWW!!! Your code sped the processing time up from an average of 0.0034 seconds per record to 0.00053 over the method I was using!!!!! Cheers mate!!!!

Comment: @Shaun I'm glad I could help! Make sure that if you think this is the correct answer to your question you click the green check mark to the left of it to mark it as "Accepted".

Answer (score 1):

You can use `similar_text()` to compare two strings and accept if the result is above e.g. 80%.

```
 similar_text($str1, $str2, $percent);
```

Example:

```
$str1 = 'AAA';
$str1 = '99999';

similar_text($str1, $str2, $percent); 
echo $percent; // e.g. 0.000

$str1 = "h*llo";
$str2 = "hello";

similar_text($str1, $str2, $percent); 
echo $percent; // e.g. 95.000
```

See more here [PHP SIMILAR TEXT](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why 80%?

Comment: I like this answer, and it would work for most things, but it's not as accurate as a method that uses actual wildcards, like fnmatch() or regex.